# ASP.NET Is it possible to handle all the null session checking in masterpage

Tags: asp.net

I have the following steps in my webpage

1) User Logs in and I set the following session variables

```
     Session("userName") = reader_login("useremail").ToString()
     Session("userId") = reader_login("user_ID").ToString()
     Session("firstName") = reader_login("firstName").ToString()
```

2) Now on my logged in VB.NET templates I reference a MasterPage called LoggedIn.Master. In Which I added the following method to check for the above null session variables. And if they null to redirect back to login page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    '#Check that User is Logged in, if not redirect to login page
    If (Session("userId") Is Nothing) Or (Session("userName") Is Nothing) Or (Session("firstName") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("site_base_url").ToString & "login/", False)
    End If
```

3) Now my question is if I want to use any above 3 Session variables in different .net templates or usercontrols referencing the above master page  do i need to AGAIN add the check

```
        If (Session("userId") Is Nothing) Or (Session("userName") Is Nothing) Or (Session("firstName") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("site_base_url").ToString & "login/", False)
    End If
```

In the respective pages or will the check in master page do. Because at the moment i.e. if in a usercontrol I attempt to do i.e.

```
customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()
```

or

```
Response.Write(Session("userName").ToString())
```

I am getting the error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question - as long as the masterpage checks the session and redirects before all your controls and page code make a reference to Session, you should be fine.

You were using `OnInit()` which seems reasonable, but see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for a good understanding of the timing of events.

Incidentally, I strongly discourage the use of ad-hoc calls to `Session` in your page and control code. Instead, I recommend you create a static SessionManager class that does the Session referencing for you. That way, you get to benefit from strong typing, and won't be able to accidentally make hard-to-debug 'session key' typos in your code like `Session["FiirstName"]`. Also, you can incorporate your null-session check right into the call for the session value:

**EXAMPLE** (in C#, sorry!)

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    private static void EnsureUserId()
    {
        if (Session["userId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("YourLogin.aspx", false);
        }
    }

    public static string FirstName
    {
        get 
        {
             EnsureUserId();
             if (Session["firstName"] == null) 
                 Session["firstName"] = ""; 
             return (string)Session["firstName"]; 
        }
        set
        { 
             Session["firstName"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey James, thanks for reply. This is what i was leaning to towards the end of my original post. I am getting errors all your my controls and page codes when the session is null for all. Eventhough I have those checks in my masterpage

Comment: Hey james thanks for that code snippet that looks cool and a lot better than what I was using before. Think I am just going to use this and forget about controlling all the session status in masterpage seems to be a royal clust %^&* :P

Comment: No worries. Just thinking though - is there a reason why you're not using standard ASP.NET Authorization for access control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Comment: Hmm never really heard of that before. Is that i.e. Forms authentication and i need to set that cookie value or something ?

Comment: Yeah, *Authorization* says what bits of your site authenticated and non-authenticated users may view. "Authentication* defines the method that you use to verify people are who they say they are. **Forms Authentication** is the easiest scheme to set up, and the resulting authentication cookie gets used automatically for Authorization. It's simpler than it sounds, and using it will save you having to re-invent the wheel ;) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper around the Session to handle null values and just call the wrapper when you access the items:

```
Public Class SessionWrapper
   Public Shared ReadOnly Property Item()
     'Access session here and check for nothing
   End Property
End Class
```

And use it like this

```
SessionWrapper.Item("itemName")
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you had pretty much answered the question here. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an http module that asks about the session objects and if they are null, it will redirect to the login page and by developing this http module, in each page request the module will do the check and then you can use it normally without checking.

Comment: Hey samir this sounds good, but no idea about these http session modules could you give an example ?

Comment: Don't think you *need* a module for that - you can check the status of the Session during the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` event in **global.asax**

Comment: Hey james I was leaning towards not using global since i only want this check on a certain aspect of the site. I.e. all the pages referencing this loggedin master page. So basically its not possible to create my session check on the master page ?

Comment: It certainly is possible, but please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle this would be to add a base class for all controls that require this session variables to be present. You can then add properties to wrap access to the session and other cool stuff and the check will work even if the controls are used with a different master page.